# Increment character works but adding doesn't. Why?

Tags: php

```
$a = 'a';
print ($a+1);
print ($a++);
print $a;
```

The output is: `1 a b`

So it is clear that increment operator did its job but I don't understand why output is '1' in case `$a+1`. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP is not C, so `'a' + 1` is not `'b'`.

`'a'` in a numeric context is `0`, and `0+1 = 1`.

```
php> echo (int)'a';
0
```

The fact that the postfix/prefix increment operators *do* work like if it was a C char seems to be a nasty "feature" of PHP. Especially since the decrement operators are a no-op in this case.

When you increment `'z'` it gets even worse:

```
php> $a = 'z';
php> echo ++$a
aa
```

Comment: What do you mean by? : "Especially since the decrement operators are a no-op in this case".

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't call it odd necessarily. It's essentially following standard mathematical rules using a base of 25 (with letters instead of numbers).

Comment: @Shubham "No-op" means "no operation", i.e. nothing happens. It's explained here right before the first example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: By the way even in c 'a'+1 is not 'b' but char('a'+1) !
I'm talking about upper cast .

Comment: PHP is damn weird! Thanks for explaination!

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I'm not sure that I'd define following Perl incrementor standard (and documenting the fact that you're following that standard) "getting worse". Annoying that decrementor isn't consistent, but this is not "unexpected behaviour" because it is fully documented

Answer (score 3):

The reason is PHP treating variables in a context specific way. It's a bit similar to Visual Basic.

The expression `'a' + 1` uses mathematical addition. In this context `a` is interpreted as a number, so it will be considered 0 (if you're familiar with C, it's like feeding the string "a" into `atoi()`).

If you'd use the expression `'a' . 1` the result would be `a1` due to it using string concatenation.

To get the result you expected (`b`), you'd have to use `chr(ord('a') + 1)`, where `ord()` explicitly returns the ASCII value of the (first) character.

`$a++` is a special case, essentially an overload looking at the ascii value instead of the value itself as the variable.

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php, "a"+1 is executed as 0+1. Where some languages (C#) will translate (string)+(int) to (string)+(string), PHP does the opposite: (int)+(int).

To force string concatenation instead: `"a" . 1` yields 'a1'.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an addition, PHP attempts to convert 'a' to an integer. Just like if you were to use atoi in C, 'a' is intepreted as 0. Therefore 0 + 1 is 1.

Comment: Yes, but why does `$a++` change the value of `$a` to `b` and not `1`?

Comment: Incrementing is not the same operation as addition. PHP follows Perl's convention. See this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php