# Encrypting Decrypting functions in c++ and php

Tags: php, c++

Ok I want to decrypt a string in php but with the same code in c++ theres a different output.

```cpp
int main()
{
   int i, x;
   char str[100];

   cout << "Please enter a string:\t";
   cin >> str;

   cout << "\nPlease choose following options:\n";
   cout << "1 = Encrypt the string.\n";
   cout << "2 = Decrypt the string.\n";
   cin >> x;

   //using switch case statements
   switch(x)
   {
      //first case for encrypting a string
      case 1:
         for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
            str[i] = str[i] + 2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is added to ASCII value

         cout << "\nEncrypted string: " << str << endl;
         break;

      //second case for decrypting a string
      case 2:
         for(i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
         str[i] = str[i] - 2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is subtracted to ASCII value

      cout << "\nDecrypted string: " << str << endl;
      break;

      default:
         cout << "\nInvalid Input !!!\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

```php
<?php

function writeMsg() {
    $str='Lqgococ';
    $i;
    for($i = 0; ($i < 100 && $str[$i] != '\0'); $i++){
    $str[$i] = $str[$i] - 2;
    echo $str;
    }
}

writeMsg(); // call the function
?>
```

In c++ The result of decrypting string Lqgococ is Joemama
But in php its -qgococ--gococ---ococ----coc-----oc------c-etc...
I have no idea whats causing this could anyone help me? Its really odd whats happening xd

Comment: Don't know much php, but your `echo` is in the wrong place at least, it should be outside the loop I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment character works but adding doesn't. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469147/increment-character-works-but-adding-doesnt-why)

Comment: Side issue: why not just use `std::string str` instead of `char str[100]`? It will make your life a lot easier.